# How to query for a parent by a child, when the parent -> child relationship is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume a standard parent-child relationship,

A <1---* B

mapped from child to parent in Hibernate/JPA, to avoid loading up a large collection of B from A. However, I want to write a query to load A based on certain attributes of B.

This works using standard JPQL,

```
select a from b join b.a where b.blah = ...
```

but when I apply an @EntityGraph annotation from Spring Data, that annotation wants to apply to B, even though I'm returning A, and all the fields on that graph are in A.

Is this the correct approach, and it's just unfortunate that Spring Data applies that annotation to both A and B, or is this approach wrong?

Comment: How does your entity graph look like? Does it work in plain JPA? is this a `Repository<A, ?>` or a `Repository<B,?>`

Comment: Graph looks like the above: A has a theoretical, unmapped collection of B, and B has a reference to A that controls. It does work in plain JPA as written, but fails when Spring tries to apply the entity graph. This particular query is run in a repo of type A, since I'm trying to return a list of A's.